# Why my custom view is invisible?

Tags: ios, objective-c, opengl-es

I have a custom view like below:

```Objective-C
@interface OpenGLCopy () {
    CAEAGLLayer *_eaglLayer;
    EAGLContext *_context;
    GLuint _colorRenderBuffer;
}
@end

@implementation OpenGLCopy

#pragma mark - life cycle
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame {
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {
        [self setupLayer];
        [self setupContext];
        [self setupRenderBuffer];
        [self setupFrameBuffer];

        [self render];
    }
    return self;
}


#pragma mark - override
+ (Class)layerClass {
    return [CAEAGLLayer class];
}

#pragma mark - private helper
- (void)setupLayer {
    _eaglLayer = (CAEAGLLayer *)self.layer;
    _eaglLayer.opaque = YES;
}

- (void)setupContext {
    _context = [[EAGLContext alloc] initWithAPI:kEAGLRenderingAPIOpenGLES2];
    if (!_context) {
        NSLog(@"failed to initialize OpenGLES 2.0 context");
        return ;
    }

    if (![EAGLContext setCurrentContext:_context]) {
        NSLog(@"failed to set current OpenGL context");
        return ;
    }
}


- (void)setupRenderBuffer {
    glGenRenderbuffers(1, &_colorRenderBuffer);
    glBindBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
    [_context renderbufferStorage:GL_RENDERBUFFER fromDrawable:_eaglLayer];
}


- (void)setupFrameBuffer {
    GLuint frameBuffer;
    glGenFramebuffers(1, &frameBuffer);
    glBindFramebuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, frameBuffer);
    glFramebufferRenderbuffer(GL_FRAMEBUFFER, GL_COLOR_ATTACHMENT0, GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
}


- (void)render {
    glClearColor(0, 104.0/255.0, 55.0/255.0, 1.0);
    glClearColor(1, 1, 1, 1);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT);

    [_context presentRenderbuffer:GL_RENDERBUFFER];
}

@end
```

But when I init this view and add it in a controller's view, I can't see my custom view. And when I debug with view hierarchy, the custom view is actually on the top.
Who can tell me why?

Comment: Try **[self.view bringSubViewToFront:yourCustomView];** in your viewcontroller

Comment: @Rohan It does not change anything. In fact, my custom view has already at index 0 in the view hierarchy, but it seems transparent. It is so weird since I set layer's `opaque` to `YES`. So I am confused.

Comment: What do you mean by invisible? Looking at your code it seems you might be missing a call to glViewport.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should check for errors in your code using `glGetError()`. This would help you at least pinpoint the issue.

By doing so I found out that your mistake is actually very small. You are calling `glBindBuffer` when binding the render buffer. You need to use `glBindRenderbuffer` so simply replace

```
glBindBuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
```

with

```
glBindRenderbuffer(GL_RENDERBUFFER, _colorRenderBuffer);
```